# CreditCard / Check details field in BillPayment object in V3 API SDK

Tags: c#, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to add a `BillPayment` object.  I did make successful call from the API explorer.  Now it is time for the C# version.  XML from the API explorer looks like this:

```
<BillPayment xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" domain="QBO" sparse="false">
<DocNumber>2</DocNumber>
<TxnDate>2015-12-15</TxnDate>
<PrivateNote>Acct. 1JK90</PrivateNote>
<Line>
    <Amount>33.00</Amount>
    <LinkedTxn>
        <TxnId>1374</TxnId>
        <TxnType>Bill</TxnType>
    </LinkedTxn>
</Line>
<VendorRef name="A Cheung Limited">160</VendorRef>
<PayType>Check</PayType>
<CheckPayment>
    <BankAccountRef name="Checking">36</BankAccountRef>
    <PrintStatus>NotSet</PrintStatus>
</CheckPayment>
<TotalAmt>33.00</TotalAmt>
</BillPayment>
```

In C# the problem is that I cannot see a field in the `BillPayment` object for `CheckPayment` tag.  Is it a bug?  Do I have to use some kind of `CustomField` array entry?  Is there any other field of `BillPayment` object which I can use to send info about a credit card/bank account?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: I am able to see the CheckPayment tag in your XML.
<CheckPayment>
    <BankAccountRef name="Checking">36</BankAccountRef>
    <PrintStatus>NotSet</PrintStatus>
</CheckPayment>

Comment: This is from API explorer.  I am asking about C# object field.

Comment: how you deserializing your xml to object? can you share the code?

Comment: I am not. This is XML from API explorer https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#BillPayment

Comment: Jaya,  There is C# wrapper which is object based. I see XML only in debug stream and serializing/deserializing is done by the wrapper.  Problem is that there is no `CheckPayment` field in the object of the `BillPayment` wrapper class.